# GridLayoutManager Customization

Tags: android, layout-manager, gridlayoutmanager, staggeredgridlayout

i want to know if there is way that i can customize `gridlayoutmanager` in android to have horizontal layout like this sketch:
[image]

i tried some layout manager that i found in Github but non of them that help me to implement this kind of layout manager.

something like this:

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends StaggeredGridLayoutManager {
public CustomLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public CustomLayoutManager(int spanCount, int orientation) {
    super(spanCount, orientation);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
}

@Override
public void setSpanCount(int spanCount) {
    super.setSpanCount(spanCount);
}}
```

any help will be appreciated
thanks

Comment: You can use multiple type of layout in adapter.

Comment: i have not access to change adapter settings. it's in android tv enviroment

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it accepted. :)

Comment: Just need time to check it :) thanks again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need the `CustomLayoutManager`. Do this to your `RecyclerView`:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(itemView.getContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? 2 : 1;//put your condition here
    }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```