# RecyclerView LayoutManager "one two one" as Sololearn's levels menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

How can we made LinearLayout manager like this:

[image]

I also have checked Linear and Grid managers but it seems that in this case we need something new.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445975/9701793

Comment: @rahat it is kinda another disposition, but I find out how to make it fit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same problem in this topic and just make it fit my question:

[RecyclerView LayoutManager different span counts on different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112291/recyclerview-layoutmanager-different-span-counts-on-different-rows/31113461)

We just create `GridLayoutManager` and override method, then simplity set it in Recycler:

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
        // 5 is the sum of items in one repeated section
        when (position % 3) {
            0 -> return 2
            1, 2 -> return 1
        }
        throw IllegalStateException("internal error")
    }
}

recycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
```